# How to do a custom deploy using ssh with Travis CI?

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, continuous-integration, travis-ci

The travis website seems to say:
[image]

But when I try to do that

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '5'
after_success:
  - cat deploy_key.pem
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - chmod 600 deploy_key.pem
  - ssh-add deploy_key.pem
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_3dd6b0b56dad_key -iv $encrypted_3dd6b0b56dad_iv
  -in deploy_key.pem.enc -out deploy_key.pem -d
```

I get

```
$ cat deploy_key.pem
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  Agent pid 3716
$ chmod 600 deploy_key.pem
$ ssh-add deploy_key.pem
  Enter passphrase for deploy_key.pem:
```

Is there some better way to do this? My end goal is just to push a my Docker container to my Digital Ocean server once the build passes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because when you create the key pair you entered something (if you enter a passphrase, you will be asked to input it later, just as you mentioned).
you can try to create another key pair without entering any passphrase, just tap enter until the key pair created.